# Cloth sim : collision with external linked group meshes

Tags: workflow, cloth-simulation

I have a scene, with some assets linked into it. Among them is a rigged character, linked by a group instance. The rig is well "proxied", and animated. I modeled a scarf, and wanted to make a cloth simulation. The part of the scarf which is around the neck of the character is parented to the neck's bone, and defined as "Pin" in the cloth parameters.

Now, I don't want the scarf to go through the body of the character, so I came back to the character's blend file, added a collider to the body, saved, and re-opened the scene. Nothing changed. The scarf still passes through the body. There is no cache applied.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried something else, which works... (with Blender 2.67b, however)

I created a new empty blend file, and linked both the character AND the scarf into it. I had to re-configure the cloth settings of the scarf because it seems these ones aren't linkable, but worked like a charm. And since it's the final "workflow" we're looking for (i.e. linking both the scarf and the character, into another "scene" .blend file), it's great !

But, it might be a bug of the 2.67 (before "bugfixes" releases)...